# Entrypoint of an OCX

Tags: windows, com, dll, activex

What are the entrypoints of an ocx ? are they same as that of com dlls ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the entrypoints are the same.
There may be other constraints on an OCX that differ from a COM DLL though.  For example, it's common (but not required) for a COM DLL to include a type library as a built-in resource.  Every OCX I've ever seen has had its type library built-in in this way, so maybe that's a requirement for an OCX?
In general the coclasses defined in an OCX (or at least some of them) are expected to be ActiveX controls, which means they should implement certain specific COM interfaces.  A plain old COM DLL has no such expectations placed upon it.